# How do I limit possible inputs of String field in TextField component of Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In HTML5 we can do `<input type="text" maxlength="3" />` but how do I same in Material-UI ?
Bellow is example Material-UI TextFiled component

```
<TextField
          id="name"
          label="Name"
          type="string"
          //maxLength="3" Or maxlength="3" Or max="3"
          margin="normal"
        />
```

Comment: Redux, But I wish they had a simple prop for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `inputProps` to the `TextField` example following:

```
<TextField
  inputProps={{
    maxLength: 10,
  }}
/>
```

Or alternative hard coded solution:

```
<TextField
  onInput={e => {
    e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value)).toString().slice(0, 12);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: An important note is that you need to use "inputProps" and not "InputProps", check that the lowecase one is the one that works.